# Microsoft Excel Server execution failed error msg when running vbs or bat script from scheduler

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a script that opens an excel file and executes several macros within  the file and closes said file.  The script runs exactly as expected when I run it from the command prompt manually.

However, when I schedule the a task to run the script, the script is executed up to the final stage and I get a pop up msg in Excel that reads “Server execution failed”.

Here are some of the things I’ve tried, all have yielded the same Excel error message:

- Schedule the task to run the vbs script using cscript.exe
- Schedule the task to run vbs script directly from cmd
- Set up a bat script to run the vbs script via cmd prompt
- Tried running 32bit and 64bit on each version
- I’ve put all  the files and scripts in the same folder and tried all of the previous three
- I’ve played with the various settings on the task scheduler to run when I am logged on/off; computer awake etc.
- Customized configuration permissions via dcomcnfg and gave the user (me) “full control”
- Dropped “Authentication Level” to “None”

Other details:

- I am using Windows 10 64bit and Office 10
- The Excel file itself is saved as an xlsb file w/size 8,741 KB
- I have three other jobs that are similar to this one and all of them run without any issues
- I have admin rights on my machine
- The script is being run as me (i.e., using my profile/account)

This is the vbs script, "macro launcher" (originally sourced from [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/how-to-automatically-run-excel-vba-macros-daily)):

```
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\person\Desktop\script\filewithmacros.xlsb"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath1 = "Module2.LoadAddins"
  MacroPath2 = "Module4.ForceCalc"
  MacroPath3 = "Module1.SendPDF"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = True  'or "False"

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = TRUE

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code 1
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath1

'Force Calculation

ExcelApp.Calculate

'Execute Macro Code 2
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath2

'For a wait for calc to finish
WScript.Sleep 180000


'Execute Macro Code 3
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath3


'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

This script runs perfectly when we run it directly from the command prompt as

[image: running from command prompt]

However, when we schedule the task to run a bat containing the same code (shown below), we get an excel error: "Server execution failed"

```
cd c:\windows\SysWOW64   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe  C:\Users\name\Desktop\script\MacroLauncher.vbs
```

The user account for the task is mine (admin rights) and I have tried both run only when logged on only/logged on or not options and both fail

[image: task action set up]

the add argument is

```
/c "C:\Users\name\Desktop\script\scriptfilename.bat"
```

[image]

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I appreciate the info, jwdonahue.  Believe I've done my best to briefly outline the problem and provided details on steps I've tried to remedy the issue.  Unfortunately, I do not know how to provide enough information to reproduce the problem as I have no idea what's causing it.  Unfortunately, my programming expertise is relatively limited.  If there are any specific clarifying questions you might have, I'm happy to try to answer them.  Thanks again.

Comment: We need to see the script and the task configuration.  There's probably something goofy about the different environments used for testing and running taskscheduler.  I am pretty sure that Excel requires the Windows shell in order to run.  Without knowing any of the details about the script or the task configuration, it's impossible for anybody to help you.

Comment: Understood, that's very helpful guidance. Give me a bit to pull it together and format and I'll update the original question.